# Fuse for radio, 12v charger, internal lights 2006 vw LT35, where is it?

Tags: electrical, vw, fuse-panel

Fuse for radio, 12v charger, internal lights 2006 vw LT35, where is it?

I can locate the fuse box on the driver's side seat, but this looks very different from Haynes Manual. It's a RHD. I cannot locate any other fuse boxes. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you check under the hood in the engine compartment?  Most vehicles have at least two fuse panels these days, one in the passenger or driver footwell and another under the hood.